# How to Setting up visual studio 2010 to set as auto-increment version of project on each build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to setting-up *visual studio 2010* to set as auto-increment version of project on each build?

Does this feature exist on `vs2010`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AssemblyInfo.cs - file doesnt exist if you're deveolping native software with c/c++ ... hence this answer is useless for a whole lot of developers out there - one could have a look into http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com ... but this extension doesnt seem to work with VS2010 although the website says otherwise - you may be good to go if you're using older versions of VS, though

Comment: for native c++ check out this series of blog posts: 1. http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/02/mapping-binaries-in-the-field-to-source-code-in-the-repository/ 2. http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/02/versioning-a-native-cc-binary-with-visual-studio/ 3. http://www.zachburlingame.com/2011/02/integrating-the-mercurial-revision-into-the-version-automatically/

Comment: The OP requested VS2010 support, this Addon doesnt work for 2010, even though the it details a workaround (tried and it doesnt work).

Answer (score 16):

Change the AssemblyInfo.cs-File:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

to

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: The only problem is that the number replaced by * doesn't always increment.

Comment: 1.0.* is always replaced with 1.0.{date}.{time] so it should be always be increment.

Comment: this method seems to work on the first rebuild but after that nothing changes. You would thing that "time" should change on every build but it does not.

Answer (score 15):

As someone else mentions the 1.0.* is always replaced with 1.0.{date}.{time] so it should be always be increment (you would have thought)

In VS2010 changing the AssemblyVersion to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] works, be warned that you must **close** the solution/project, **re-open it** then **re-build it** (not build) to refresh/change the build+revision values.

The date/time appears to be obtained from the time the project is opened thus the close/re-open to refresh the revision/build values, I guess this is useful if you are changing various bits within the project in one go and it won't keep changing the AssemblyVersion possibly breaking other bits.

```
To return the date from the build value:
   DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, build, DateValue("01/01/2000"))
   ' build is the number of days from 1/1/2000
To return the time from the revision value:
   Date.FromOADate(revision / 1800 / 24) 
   ' depending on your timezone you may have DST/BST issue with resulting time
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning you need to close and reopen solution, does make new users wonder why their build numbers do not change.

Comment: The answer given doesnt work for Visual Studio 2010, which is what the OP requested for.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the autobuildincrement method and had problems with Visual Studio 2010 however I found a way to make it work.  Set "Increment Before Build to false.  Then even in Visual Studio 2010 the assempblyinfo.cs file will be updated after each build.

Note the assembly info on your dll won't change on your first build, but it will after that.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the auto build version tool but you haven't made this clear http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Parse(@"1/1/2000")
    .AddDays(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
      ).FileBuildPart)
    .AddSeconds(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
      ).FilePrivatePart * 2)
```