# Increment Build Number to +1 for each build in VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am looking for auto increment my build number to +1 each time I build my application. 
I have done little research about this and I found few ways.

1. Change [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
   but it works with days and time having some calculation get the values for each build.
2. writing a class file to increment value for each build.This is used for VS-2008/2006
3. To use http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

I would like to achieve what option-3 is doing by using option-1, Is it possible ?

(or)

is there any better way to achieve my solution ?

Comment: "Set "Increment Before Build to false. Then even in Visual Studio 2010 the assempblyinfo.cs file will be updated after each build.

Note the assembly info on your dll won't change on your first build, but it will after that.
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457589/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-set-as-auto-increment-version-of-project-on-eac

Comment: What's wrong with option 3?

Comment: I am developing this product for a client and I am not sure whether it is free to use or not.